# Text parsing and calculator (calculate Java heap memory)

Tags: python, parsing, logging, child-process

I'm writing small tool, which must execute `jmap -heap`, write output to log, then takes some data from log and calculate used memory.

I added some `debug` to it.

```
# JVM with jmap statistic
def java_heap_save(log):

  subprocess.call('jmap -heap %s > %s' % (java_pid, log), shell=True, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)

  with open(log, 'r') as logread:

    data = logread.readlines()

    # this is just to display 'what will parsing'
    print(data)

    # here is two list, first - index of item in data, second - for message on terminal
    nums = [40, 35, 30, 25, 20]
    messages = ['PS Perm Generation', 'PS Old Generation', 'Yong To Space', 'Yong From Space', 'Yong Eden Space']
    # I don't found how to create dynamic variable names, so use dictionary
    count_names = {}
    count_numbers = 1

    for num, mess in zip(nums, messages):
#      print(mess + ' used '+ str((int(data[num].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)) + ' KB;')
       # from log we got data in bytes, convert here to megabatyes
       res = (int(data[num].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)
       print('%s used %s KB;' % (mess, res))
       # save value
       count_names[count_numbers] = int(res)
       count_numbers += 1

    print('\nJVM Heap memory stats:\n')
    mem_total = (int(data[7].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024 / 1024)
    print('MemTotal = %s MB;' % mem_total)

    # next few lines - my first attempt, then was rewrited to loop above

#    ps_perm_gen = (int(data[40].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)
#    print('PS Perm Generation used = %s KB;' % ps_perm_gen)
#    ps_old_gen = (int(data[35].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)
#    print('PS Old Generation used = %s KB;' % ps_old_gen)
#    young_to_space = (int(data[30].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)
#    print('Yong To Space used = %s KB;' % young_to_space)
#    young_from_space = (int(data[25].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)
#    print('Yong From Space used = %s KB;' % young_from_space)
#    young_eden_space = (int(data[20].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)
#    print('Yong Eden Space used = %s KB;' % young_eden_space)
#    heap_total_used = ((ps_perm_gen + ps_old_gen + young_to_space + young_eden_space) / 1024)

    # count total used memory
    heap_total_used = ((count_names[1] + count_names[2] + count_names[3] + count_names[4] + count_names[5]) / 1024)
    print('\nTotal heap used: %s MB;' % heap_total_used)
    # count % from total avail memory
    heap_percentage_used = heap_total_used * 100 / mem_total
    print('Heap percentage used: %s%%' % heap_percentage_used)
```

Then it is called like:

```
java_heap_save(jmap_log)
```

Output:

> ```
> $ ./monitor.py
> ...
> JUST FOR DEBUG
>
> ['\n', 'using thread-local object allocation.\n', 'Parallel GC with 2 thread(s)\n', '\n', 'Heap Configuration:\n', '   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40\n', '   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70\n', '   MaxHeapSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)\n', '   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)\n', '   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB\n', '   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)\n', '   NewRatio         = 2\n', '   SurvivorRatio    = 8\n', '   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)\n', '   MaxPermSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)\n', '\n', 'Heap Usage:\n', 'PS Young Generation\n', 'Eden Space:\n', '   capacity = 334626816 (319.125MB)\n', '   used     = 164795568 (157.1613006591797MB)\n', '   free     = 169831248 (161.9636993408203MB)\n', '   49.247567774126026% used\n', 'From Space:\n', '   capacity = 11927552 (11.375MB)\n', '   used     = 2293760 (2.1875MB)\n', '   free     = 9633792 (9.1875MB)\n', '   19.23076923076923% used\n', 'To Space:\n', '   capacity = 11337728 (10.8125MB)\n', '   used     = 0 (0.0MB)\n', '   free     = 11337728 (10.8125MB)\n', '   0.0% used\n', 'PS Old Generation\n', '   capacity = 715849728 (682.6875MB)\n', '   used     = 249838952 (238.2649917602539MB)\n', '   free     = 466010776 (444.4225082397461MB)\n', '   34.90103330737034% used\n', 'PS Perm Generation\n', '   capacity = 104005632 (99.1875MB)\n', '   used     = 95693760 (91.26068115234375MB)\n', '   free     = 8311872 (7.92681884765625MB)\n', '   92.00824816871456% used\n']
>
>
> PS Perm Generation used 93450 KB;
> PS Old Generation used 243983 KB;
> Yong To Space used 0 KB;
> Yong From Space used 2240 KB;
> Yong Eden Space used 160933 KB;
>
> JVM Heap memory stats:
>
> MemTotal = 1024 MB;
>
> Total heap used: 488 MB;
> Heap percentage used: 47%
> ```

What I can improve here?

In fact - I don't like how I realized 'log read' code, I mean this:

```python
int(data[SOME_NUMBER_HERE_ENTERED_MANUALLY].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)
```

**CentOS** 6,5, **Python** 2.6

Answer (score 4):

First off, using `%` for string formatting is deprecated if you're using Python 2.6 or higher. You should be using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) instead. Here's an example of how you can use `str.format`.

```
# str.format without positional or named parameters
print "{} {}".format("Hello", "world")

# str.format with positional parameters
print "{1} {0}".format("world", "Hello")

# str.format with named paramters
print "{word1} {word2}".format(word1="Hello", word2="world")
```

Secondly, all the commented out lines of code, like `#    ps_perm_gen = (int(data[40].split(' ')[-2]) / 1024)` should be entirely removed. Stuff like this is an eyesore to look at.

You also have a lot of not-so-great variable names. A few examples include `nums`, `res`, `data`, and `count_numbers`, Variable names should describe the purpose of the variable as best as possible.

Finally, improve your comments. Right now, not very many of your comments are very good. A few examples include:

```
# next few lines - my first attempt, then was rewrited to loop above
# this is just to display 'what will parsing'
# save value
```

Comments should describe hard-to-understand parts of code in detail, but only if needed. If the code is clear enough to understand, then don't use a comment.